# How to get access token from api in react native

Tags: react-native, oauth-2.0, fetch, access-token

I am using react native and i want to get the access token from api which is created in django using oAuth 2 authentication

i am passing all the details which are required but i do not know why i am getting error of unsupported grant type

```
fetch('MyApiUrl', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                'grant_type': 'password',
                'username': 'MyUserNameSettedInApi',
                'password': 'PasswordSettedInApi',
                'client_id': 'MyClientId',
                'client_secret': 'MyClientSecret',
                'scope': 'read Write'
            })
        })
            .then((response) => response)     <----tried response.json() but giving same error of grant type
            .then((responseData) => {
                console.log(responseData);
            })
```

My expected result is i want access token should display 
and what i am getting is

```
Response {type: "default", status: 400, ok: false, statusText: undefined, headers: Headers, …}
headers: Headers {map: {…}}
ok: false
status: 400
statusText: undefined
type: "default"
url: "http://MyUrl"
_bodyInit: "{"error": "unsupported_grant_type"}"
_bodyText: "{"error": "unsupported_grant_type"}"
__proto__: Object
```

please help
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

`tried response.json() but giving same error of grant type` - this is answer from Your oauth server.

`response.json()` transform your response data into json decoded string.

Change Your code to this:

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('grant_type', 'password');
formData.append('username', 'MyUserNameSettedInApi');
formData.append('password', 'PasswordSettedInApi');
formData.append('client_id', 'MyClientId');
formData.append('client_secret', 'MyClientSecret');
formData.append('scope', 'read Write');

fetch('MyApiUrl', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    body: formData
})
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((responseData) => {
    console.log(responseData);
});
```

Comment: thanks for fast response but api working correctly on postman with grant type password

Comment: Check my updated answer, and check what content-type you use in postman and how data are pushed.

Comment: also check that thread: https://github.com/RealmTeam/django-rest-framework-social-oauth2/issues/56

Comment: in postman content type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded so sould i write this type in accept

Comment: if you have use application/x-www-form-urlencoded then don't sen JSON but form-data (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_forms_through_JavaScript). If You want to send it as a json like in your code then You need to set content-type to  `application/json` and activate handling json data in oauth like in my example. You have mixed formats and content types in your code now.

Comment: so that means  `OAUTH2_PROVIDER = {
    'OAUTH2_BACKEND_CLASS': 'oauth2_provider.oauth2_backends.JSONOAuthLibCore',
}` this code will handle my json data give to api as `x-www-form-urlencoded` format

Comment: nope, it will consume your json data with  `Content-Type: application/json` header (you need to use it in your code)

Comment: sorry but i am not getting after consumption how my api will use that data for authentication

Comment: thanks for giving me hint i did it with qs library i used only qs.stringify() in body

Comment: My solution does this same with pure JavaScript - no additional libraries are required.

Answer (score 0):

Install qs library

```
npm install qs
```

Import it in your app and then you'll be able to send it.
Use **qs.stringify** as shown below

```
fetch('http://localhost:8888/o/token',
       {
         method: 'POST',
         headers: {
           'Accept': 'application/json',
           'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;'
         },
         body: qs.stringify({
           'grant_type': 'password',
            'username': 'MyUserNameSettedInApi',
            'password': 'PasswordSettedInApi',
            'client_id': 'MyClientId',
            'client_secret': 'MyClientSecret',
         })
       })
```

Answer (score 0):

I also got that same issue of `"{"error": "unsupported_grant_type"}"` for that, I just pass all the body parameters directly without using `JSON.stringify({});` It works for me, find the example code below.

```
body: 'grant_type=password&username=MyUserName&password=MyPassword'
```

you need to update the body section only.

```
    fetch('MyApiUrl', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    body: 'grant_type=password&username=MyUserName&password=MyPassword'
  })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(token => console.log(token))
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Hope this will help you.